# Streaming videos using Wowza

Tags: video, streaming

I need to view the streaming videos in my website. For that I have searched and get the answer to use Wowza (just like FMS).

I need to know how can I stream the videos using Wowza and how to store the video files in the server.

Have to use any encoder for streaming the videos?

Comment: Check out http://www.wowza.com/forums/, the quick start guide, tutorials and documentation in particular. 
As an alternative to wowza, you might want to take a look at red5 http://www.red5.org/

Answer (score 1):

As DennisJaamann suggested; http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?3-quick-start-guide.

Basically - recorded video content needs to be uploaded to your server, FTP or SCP should do the job nicely.

If you are streaming live - then you will require a live encoder. If your On-Demand content is not encoded using the h264 codec, then you will also require an OD encoder. There are lots of options for this.

For playback - you can use any flash player you like, Wowza provide an example player with the install, there's also; OSMF Strobe Media Playback, JWPlayer (longtailvideo), Flowplayer - and lots and lots of others!

Providing some more information regarding your exact goal would be helpful, and enable us to provide a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

Wowza is the best media server for live video streaming solution

Flow of Live Streaming:

When user records the video from web or mobile, Wowza media server will encode the video and send decoded as per the required format based on latency

We have used Wowza media server and JW player to control streaming on player side.